# ExtentReports - Java ExtentReports FreeMarker Template Error: freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException

Tags: java, testing, extentreports

```
SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
Template inclusion failed (for parameter value "partials/exceptıon.ftl"):
Template not found for name "spark/partials/exceptıon.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports, basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */).

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #include "partials/${view.toString()}...  [in template "spark/spark.spa.ftl" at line 27, column 36]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:164)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:371)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:321)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:244)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:645)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:108)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:335)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:341)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:314)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:52)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.getSource(FreemarkerTemplate.java:39)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.writeTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:45)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.AbstractFileReporter.processTemplate(AbstractFileReporter.java:74)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter.flush(ExtentSparkReporter.java:149)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:121)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:113)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:310)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:226)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ReactiveSubject.onFlush(ReactiveSubject.java:83)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.onFlush(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:279)
    at com.hyr.extentreports.Deneme2.main(Deneme2.java:11)
Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "spark/partials/exceptıon.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports, basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */).
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2957)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:3062)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:162)
    ... 24 more

Eki 14, 2023 10:57:24 ÖS com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter flush
SEVERE: An exception occurred
FreeMarker template error:
Template inclusion failed (for parameter value "partials/exceptıon.ftl"):
Template not found for name "spark/partials/exceptıon.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports, basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */).

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #include "partials/${view.toString()}...  [in template "spark/spark.spa.ftl" at line 27, column 36]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:164)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:371)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:321)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:244)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:645)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:108)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:335)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:341)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:314)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.processTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:52)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.getSource(FreemarkerTemplate.java:39)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.templating.FreemarkerTemplate.writeTemplate(FreemarkerTemplate.java:45)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.AbstractFileReporter.processTemplate(AbstractFileReporter.java:74)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter.flush(ExtentSparkReporter.java:149)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:121)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter$1.onNext(ExtentSparkReporter.java:113)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:310)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:226)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ReactiveSubject.onFlush(ReactiveSubject.java:83)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.onFlush(AbstractProcessor.java:96)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:279)
    at com.hyr.extentreports.Deneme2.main(Deneme2.java:11)
Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "spark/partials/exceptıon.ftl".
The name was interpreted by this TemplateLoader: ClassTemplateLoader(resourceLoaderClass=com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports, basePackagePath="templates/" /* relatively to resourceLoaderClass pkg */).
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2957)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.getTemplateForInclusion(Environment.java:3062)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:162)
    ... 24 more
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>



public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("target/Spark.html");
        extent.attachReporter(spark);
        extent.createTest("MyFirstTest")
                .log(Status.PASS, "This is a logging event for MyFirstTest, and it passed!");
        extent.flush();
    }
```

I watched all the extentreport installation videos, but I did not see anyone with such a problem. The strange thing is that when I install a friend's smoothly running ExtentReport project on my own computer, I get the same error. So I think the problem is not project-related, but you can't tell.

```
I added extentreports adjustments to my project in different ways, both simple and complex, but the result did not change. I created new projects, but the result did not change. I deleted everything, Java, Intellij, Maven, and reinstalled it, but the result was the same. I watched the videos exactly from start to finish and still got the same result. I saw that no one is using the "exception.ftl" file, which was stated to be missing in the error I received.
```

Please help me.s

Comment: Very likely to be a path issue of where you templates are located.  Update your question with a tree structure of your project indicating where the templates are located.  Should probably be in `src/main/resources/...`

Comment: There are no templates, in all the things I watch and read, no one I see uses any templates, at least in the beginning. and they can create html reports. They do not specify any path. Install dependencies, write 3 or 4 lines of code and voila, reporting. If what you mean is something different, could you please explain in detail? thanks for your comment. @AndrewL

Comment: OK, I see now - this ExtentReports library must be using Freemarker, rather than your code directly.  You need to go back to those authors for help on how to configure their library.  I would have expected that they *bundle* the report templates in the Library, but since you are getting this error perhaps they do not bundle with the Jar to allow template customisation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So what exactly do I need to do? Can you guide me? @AndrewL